# How do I plot my function for x = 5,6,...,50?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm working on the [secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) and I've written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def calc_probability(r,n):
    sum = 0
    for x in range(r,n):
        sum += 1 / (x - 1)
    return sum*((r - 1)/n)

def calc_optimal_k(n):
    k = 0
    probability_k = 0
    for r in range(2,n):
        if (calc_probability(r,n) > probability_k):
            probability_k = calc_probability(r,n)
            k = r
    return k

x = np.arange(5,50,1)
plt.plot(x,calc_optimal_k(x))
plt.show()
```

I want to plot calc_optimal_k() for n = 5,...,50, but when I run this script I get the following error:

```
line 12, in calc_optimal_k 
   for r in range(2,n):
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Apparently my formulation of x is incorrect. I've looked at the following [example](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) and I read that x needs to be a sequence of scalars, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If x = [5,6,...] then the function calc_optimal_k should work fine right? (I'm obviously mistaken)

I've tried different ways to write x but nothing seems to help. When I define x = 5, I don't get an error but my graph looks like this

[image: "Graph" when x = 5]

which doesn't get me anywhere..

**Question:** How do I plot my function calc_optimal_k for x = 5,6,...,50?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to change `for r in range(2,n)` to either `for r in n` or `for r in range(2,n.shape[0])` depending on what you want.

Comment: Use `plt.plot(x, np.vectorize(calc_optimal_k)(x))`, such that the function is called with all scalars from the array individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function with a numpy array, but it expects a scalar `n`. You could overcome this problem by calling it with a scalar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def calc_probability(r,n):
    sum = 0
    for x in range(r,n):
        sum += 1 / (x - 1)
    return sum*((r - 1)/n)

def calc_optimal_k(n):
    k = 0
    probability_k = 0
    for r in range(2,n):
        if (calc_probability(r,n) > probability_k):
            probability_k = calc_probability(r,n)
            k = r
    return k

x = np.arange(5,50,1)
y = np.array([calc_optimal_k(n) for n in x])
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I am not sure, why `x` (and hence my `y`) is a numpy array in the first place. If you want to use a vectorised approach, you have to use [numpy's math library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html) in your called functions, too. Otherwise the math library will try to convert arrays into scalars, which afaik is only possible for arrays of length one.